# Yii2 url generation issue

Tags: yii2, codeception

In Yii2 Codeception acceptance test I am using PhantomJs as a browser.

Started server successfully

```
 phantomjs --webdriver=4444
```

When running  test with

```
codecept run
```

It isn't working as expected.
My code is:

```
class LoginCest
{
    public function ensureThatLoginWorks(AcceptanceTester $I)
    {
        $I->amOnPage(Url::toRoute('/site/login'));
        $I->see('Enq','b');

    }
}
```

When changing it to

```
$I->amOnPage(Url::toRoute(['/../../../site/login']));
```

its works fine because it takes url as myApp/web/**usr/local/bin**/site/login

Its adding automatically **usr/local/bin**

is there any solution for this apart from this **$I->amOnPage(Url::toRoute(['/../../../site/login']));**

Comment: Worked fine whe replacing $I->amOnPage('/site/login');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Worked fine whe  replacing*

```
 $I->amOnPage(Url::toRoute(['/../../../site/login']));
```

with this

> $I->amOnPage('/site/login');